# trying to make a tree algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char a[52];
struct node {
char var;
node* parent;

node() {
    parent = NULL;
}
};

node n[26];

void printLevel(node b[],int k) {
if (b[k].parent == NULL) {
    cout << b[k].var << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "-";
    printLevel(b[k].parent, k);
}
}

int main() {
int num;
cin >> num;
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    cin >> a[i];
}

for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    cout << a[i];
}

for (int i = 0; i < (num / 2) + 1; i++) {
    n[i].var = 'A' + i;
}

for (int i = 1; i < num; i + 2) {
    int parent;
    int temp;
    for (int j = 0; j < (num/2)+1; j++) {
        if (n[j].var == a[i]) {
            temp = a[i - 1];
            parent = j;
            }
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < (num / 2) + 1; k++) {
        if (n[k].var == temp) {
            n[parent].parent = &n[k];
        }
    }
}


for (int i = 0; i < (num / 2) + 1; i++)
{
    printLevel(n, i);
}


return 0;
}
```

this is the code I have. the input will be sth like

```
8
A B A C B D B E
```

where the first line is how much inputs I want and the second line is
odd numbers are the parent nodes, and the even numbers are the child nodes to the previous odd number.

and the output I want is

```
A
-B
-C
--D
--E
```

So I basically want to show the level of the tree with "-" 
I don't know what I'm doing wrong here some help would be really appreciated.

Comment: For the shown input, what is the *actual* output? Have you tried stepping through the code line by line in a debugger?

Comment: actually there's no output when I run the code... it just stops

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform BFS (Level order traversal), and prepend the level number of "-"  before nodes value.